# Logistic regression with directional data as IV

Tags: circular-statistics

I am looking for good references on using directional data (measure of direction in degrees) as an independent variable in regression; ideally, it would also be useful for hierarchical nonlinear models (the data are nested).  I am also interested in directional data more generally.

I have found a text by Mardia, which I am going to get, but wondered if there were good articles.

I am more interested in practical articles about how to deal with this type of data than in theorems and proofs, or formal statements of distributions and such.  Thanks

UPDATE  I have got the Mardia text, which is quite comprehensive.  After some more reading, I may be back with more questions.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225729/what-are-periodic-version-of-splines

Comment: Thanks!  I'm curious - how did you find my question from 8 years ago and remember to put this there?  I mean, I appreciate it, but I'm amazed!

Comment: From time to time (often) I just go through, say som old questions from some user, and upvotes, edits, flags, comments as needed, or maybe even answering ... and I think this site can become more useful with crossreferencing, and such comments are stored as crossreferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest applying a transform which deals with periodicity. i.e. $\lim_{x \to 360} f(x) = f(0)$. An easy option is to take the sin and cos, and put them both as covariates in the model.